# Serve multiple map styles with mapnik and mod_tile from one server & database

Tags: mapnik, mod-tile

I struggle to set up two different map styles for the mapnik-osm rendering tool chain. According to some help I already found on gis.stackexchange, I set up the `renderd.conf` for two map styles. But I can't get it to work. When I enter the URL for the second map style (http://myserverurl/print/0/0/0.png) the browser says `"The requested URL was not found on this server."` With the default map style it is no problem (http://myserverurl/osm/0/0/0.png).

I couldn't find any other setting in the `mod_tile` or `renderd` config files to enable the "print" map style to work. The `renderd.conf` looks like this:

```
[renderd]
stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
num_threads=10
tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile

[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/3.0/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
font_dir_recurse=false

[default]
URI=/osm/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
TILESIZE=256
XML=/home/osm/openstreetmap-carto-4.24.1/style.xml
DESCRIPTION=Default map style
;ATTRIBUTION=&copy;<a href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a> and <a href=\"http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w\
iki/Contributors\">contributors</a>, <a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>
;HOST=http://myserverurl
;SERVER_ALIAS=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org
;SERVER_ALIAS=http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org
;HTCPHOST=proxy.openstreetmap.org

[print]
URI=/print/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
TILESIZE=512
XML=/home/osm/openstreetmap-carto-4.24.1/print/style.xml
DESCRIPTION=print map style
;ATTRIBUTION=&copy;<a href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a> and <a href=\"http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w\
iki/Contributors\">contributors</a>, <a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>
;HOST=http://myserverurl
;SERVER_ALIAS=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org
;SERVER_ALIAS=http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org
;HTCPHOST=proxy.openstreetmap.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was: In the `/var/www/` directory was only an `osm` folder (http://myserverurl/osm/0/0/0.png worked). I created another directory named like the additional mapstyle (`print`). And gave the permission `chmod -R 755 /var/www`.

After a restart of Apache it now serves the other map style through http://myserverurl/print/0/0/0.png.